# laravel building a package

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

Trying to build a package, for a ticketing system, but i obviously have a typo or misconception on the process.

```
{
    "name": "pureintellect/tickets",
    "description": "Laravel Ticketing system",
    "license": "MIT",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Pureintellect\\Tickets\\": "src/"

        }
    }
}
```

This is a Laravel 5.3 project. The package I'm writing is in

```
packages/pureintellect/tickets
```

the service provider is

```
packages/pureintellect/tickets/src/TicketsServiceProvider.php
```

Error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
 Class 'Pureintellect\Tickets\TicketsServiceProvider' not found
```

Ive tried different paths such as

```
"Pureintellect\\Tickets\\": "src/"
"Pureintellect\\Tickets\\": "packages/pureintellect/tickets/"
"Pureintellect\\Tickets\\": "packages/pureintellect/tickets/src"
```

What am I doing wrong? I have already tried composer dump-autoload -o and composer update as other message have suggested. I'm sure its something to do with file path or namespacing... but maybe I've just been staring at it too long. As I'm sure we all know its the little bugs that take 90% of our time. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone! I figured it out. Turns out the issue was permissions. I needed to make sure the group had execute permisisons. Once i fixed that things started working.

Answer (score 0):

If your package is in `packages/pureintellect/tickets/src` then your autoloader should point to that...

```
"Pureintellect\\Tickets\\": "packages/pureintellect/tickets/src/"
```

Comment: Is your TicketsServiceProvider namespaced as `Pureintellect\Tickets`?

Comment: Yes. I just double checked

Comment: I don't know what all debugging you've done.  Check  `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` for  `'Pureintellect\\Tickets\\` => array($baseDir . '/packages/pureintellect/tickets/src')`.  If that exists, try including the file and calling the class manually.  Something has got to lead you in the right direction, as this line should make that class work if it is namespaced correctly and in that directory.